# NullPointerException When Making an Animation

Tags: android, animation, nullpointerexception, android-viewpager, android-context

I have one really annoying problem in my android app and I just cant figure out what the problem is.

I'm trying to make an animation object like this:

```
Animation anim = AnimationUtils.makeInChildBottomAnimation(Myclass.this);
```

This is the LogCat:

```
01-01 15:25:37.730: E/AndroidRuntime(10277): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-01 15:25:37.730: E/AndroidRuntime(10277): java.lang.NullPointerException
01-01 15:25:37.730: E/AndroidRuntime(10277):    at android.content.ContextWrapper.getResources(ContextWrapper.java:81)
01-01 15:25:37.730: E/AndroidRuntime(10277):    at android.view.animation.AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(AnimationUtils.java:71)
01-01 15:25:37.730: E/AndroidRuntime(10277):    at android.view.animation.AnimationUtils.makeInChildBottomAnimation(AnimationUtils.java:253)
```

Im guessing that it has something to do with getting the context of the class.
I have also tried by loading an animation from a xml file and making an alhpa animation but i get NPE on both of those.

I am calling `setContentView();` in `onCreate` so I just cant see why i get this error.
In this class i declare a `ViewPagerAdapter` and set it to the `ViewPager` in my xml layout.
In the adapter-class iam checking for long clicks on the `ImageView` that shows in the `ViewPager`. When the user long clicks i call a static method in the class that i am getting the error in. The static method in turn makes a new object that calls a non static method like this:

```
    ViewPagerClass d = new ViewPagerClass();
    d.showMenu();
```

In the `showMenu` method i try to make this animation that will fade in the `RelativeLayout` but that's where it fails.

Comment: What exactly represents `ViewPagerClass`?

Comment: @Luksprog I have got two classes, on is ViewPagerClass and the other is ViewPagerAdapter. In viewpagerclass i call setcontentview(); and viewpageradapter is like the helper class where i fill the imageview in the viewpager from a bitmap array. When someone long clicks the imageview i call a static method in ViewPagerClass from the viewpageradapter class. In that method i call a non static method in viewpagerclass where i try to make an animation that will show a relativelayout. I understand if that didn't make much sense

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following your comment, it appears you're instantiating the `ViewPagerClass` class which is an `Activity`. This is an incorrect thing to do as an `Activity` manually instantiated will not have a valid `Context` associated and you'll get exceptions when trying to use that nonexistent `Context`. Activities are meant to be created and managed by the Android system.

> When the user long clicks i call a static method in the class that i
>   am getting the error in. The static method in turn makes a new object
>   that calls a non static method like this:

Don't do this. If the `ViewPagerAdapter` and `ViewPagerClass` classes are in different files then modify the `ViewPagerAdapter` constructor so you pass it a `Context` reference(an `Activity`(`ViewPagerClass`) is a `Context`) and assign `this` or `ViewPagerClass.this` when you create the `ViewPagerAdapter` instance. Then you would use that `Context` reference in `ViewPagerAdapter` to call the `showMenu()` method on an image long click.

Comment: Actually im already passing the context of ViewPagerClass to the constructor in the Adapter-class. I will try what you said! Thanks!

Comment: Thank you so much! I got it working by passing the Activity context to the adapter when instantiating, and when i called the static showMenu() in the adapter class i passed the context that i received from the constructor. In the showMenu() i called the nonstatic method and just passed the context again and used that when I made the animation. Not very good coding maybe but at least it works!